# Doctrine query cache & update

Tags: php, orm, doctrine, doctrine-orm

Doctrine 2 query caching was a little surprising for me. I had two update queries that follow one-by-one:

```
function upd($user, $passwordHash) {
    $qb = $this->entityManager->createQueryBuilder()
        ->update(UserEntity::__class, 'u')
        ->set('u.password', '?1')
        ->where('u = ?0')
        ->setParameters(array($user, $passwordHash));
    $qb->getQuery()->execute();
}
```

I updated password with 2 different values (ex. A, B), but user was the same:

```
upd($user, 'A');
upd($user, 'B');
```

The first query really updated database row. But the second just didn't make any changes in DB after execution.

Trying to solve this problem I found some workaround:

```
$qb->getQuery()->useQueryCache(false)->execute();
```

After disabling QueryCache both two queries changes DB row.

**So, the questions are:** why doctrine uses 1st query cache in 2nd UPDATE query? And why doctrine uses cache while it's two queries with different parameter ($passwordHash)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem was found. It is an issue in doctrine 2 ORM code. My $user entity has inheritance, so the update uses Doctrine\ORM\Query\Exec\MultiTableUpdateExecutor. In that executor:

```
//FIXME (URGENT): With query cache the parameter is out of date. Move to execute() stage.
```

[Source](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Exec/MultiTableUpdateExecutor.php#L108).

So the only workaround for now is to disable query cache for multitable updates:

```
$qb->getQuery()->useQueryCache(false)->execute();
```

I created [new bug](http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DDC-2090) for it.

Comment: Fixed since Doctrine2 ORM 2.3.3 and above